# Lenovo Thinkpad T440s Fedora 20 WiFi authentication problem

Tags: fedora, wifi, thinkpad

In some WiFi networks, consistently in hotels so far, my computer cannot connect and prompts that authentication failed, when the password is correct. This is a very annoying problem that I don't know how to fix. I think it happened in Ubuntu a while back and Fedora 20 now. The card is Intel 7260. If anybody could help that would be great.

Added paste of journalctl log:  http://pastebin.com/tKcJBPWT

Comment: Please ad more info: types of authentication, logs from `NetworkManager` or `journalctl`...

Comment: @dawud Thanks, I can't print logs because I'm on my tablet (no internet), but I can answer questions about them. how do I print the log for networkmanager? The type of authentication in this case is wpa2.

Comment: You can try opening `journalctl -f` in a terminal and try connecting via wi-fi.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't one of the hotel WiFi's where you have to browse to a URL and provide the password there? When I've been travelling that's been the case of late. I'm using Fedora 19 BTW. I also have a Thinkpad T410.

Comment: Yes, it was a hotel when I posted but the same problem is now happening in my grandpa's apartment.

Answer (score 1):

This line in the log:

```
<info> (wlp3s0): device state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets')
```

means there is no passphrase setup. Add it using:

```
$ nmcli connection edit polina
```

once greeted with the `nmcli` prompt, type:

```
nmcli> goto 802-11-wireless-security
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> set psk
Enter 'psk' value: supersecretpassphrase
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> save
Connection 'polina' (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx) sucessfully saved.
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> back
nmcli> save
Connection 'polina' (xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) sucessfully saved.
nmcli> quit
```

Then you should be able to:

```
$ nmcli connection up polina
```

Check the output of `journalctl -f` while attempting a connection to see if the error is gone.

You can also use the Network Manager graphical interface if you feel more comfortable with it.

Comment: This didnt work. The password was set up in the first place correctly, but for some reason the computer thinks it's an authentication problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Idea #1 - WiFi authentication through Web?

I would be suspicious of the WiFi being provided by the Hotel. When I've traveled I've encountered hotel WiFi where I've had to browse to a web page before I've been able to get on their WiFi. You can check to see if you've gotten an IP address prior to connecting like this:

```
$ nmcli dev list iface $(iwgetid | awk '{print $1}') | grep IP4
IP4-SETTINGS.ADDRESS:           192.168.1.110
IP4-SETTINGS.PREFIX:            24 (255.255.255.0)
IP4-SETTINGS.GATEWAY:           192.168.1.1
IP4-DNS1.DNS:                   192.168.1.8
IP4-DNS2.DNS:                   192.168.1.5
```

You'll typically get an IP, but you won't be able to access the internet until you've authenticated with a web portal at the hotel.

#### Idea #2 - Wireless N?

I'd attempt to disable your WiFi's wireless N feature. You can do so by unloading the WiFi driver and then reload it like so:

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

See this post for more details on this, titled: [WiFi not working after restoring from hibernation (authentication times out)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137021/wifi-not-working-after-restoring-from-hibernation-authentication-times-out/137034#137034).

Comment: It's not just hotels. I think it has something to do with wpa2.

Comment: Thanks, but your second suggestion doesn't fix the problem. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Flowers - can you show the output from `iwconfig` for the hotel?